# Find the radius of convergence of this complex series

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the radius of convergence
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{\sin(\sqrt{3}n\pi)}$$

**My approach:** Since that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{\sin(\sqrt{3}n\pi)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sin(\sqrt{3}n\pi)}\cdot (z-0)^{n}$$
let, $$a_{n}=\frac{1}{\sin(\sqrt{3}n\pi)} \implies a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{\sin(\sqrt{3}(n+1)\pi)}$$
by definition we can find the radius of convergence for the series as $$R:=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\right|=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{\frac{1}{\sin(\sqrt{3}n\pi)}}{\frac{1}{\sin(\sqrt{3}(n+1)\pi)}} \right|=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{\sin(\sqrt{3}(n+1)\pi)}{\sin(\sqrt{3}n\pi)} \right|$$
but how can I continue from here?

---

We can define the radius of convergence as $$R:=\frac{1}{L}$$where $$L=\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}$$

Now, the problem is to find  $L$, since that $$L=\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{1}{\sin(\sqrt{3}n\pi)}  \right|}$$

how can I calculate that $\limsup$? I tried to follow the suggestion of the comments, however either I do not understand some of their suggestions or maybe I do not know those topics that they mention. My idea is to try to narrow down $a_{n}$ and then study its behavior a bit, but I'm stuck with that part of the problem.

Comment: Developing the upper sin could be interesting .

Comment: You forget that, and use $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector It's to say use the definition  $R:=\frac{1}{\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}}$?

Comment: Yes, sure. Given the poor approximability of quadratic irrationals, $\sqrt{3}n$ can't too close to an integer, so the $\sin$ can't be too small (and of course, it can't be bigger than $1$).

Comment: how can I calculate the $\limsup$ of $\sqrt[n]{\left| \frac{1}{\sin(\sqrt{3}n\pi)} \right|}$?

Comment: $\lim\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ (don't forget the limit!) is not the definition of the radius of convergence. It's one of the formulas to calculate it, which doesn't even work in all cases. The correct definition is $R:=\sup\{\vert z\vert\in\mathbb C~\vert~\sum_k a_k(z-z_0)^k<\infty\}$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos You're right. This a typo, thank you :-)

Comment: @ProfessorVector Can you show more details in your hint? I can't calculate the $\limsup$ :-( Thank you so much.

Comment: Find the continued fraction for $1/\sqrt3$. That gives you a sequence of $n$ for which $n\pi\sqrt3$ is close to a multiple of $\pi$, so the sine is small.

Comment: @Empy2 Small, but not small enough. $|n\sqrt{3}-k|\ge C/n$, the sine doesn't change much, and $\sqrt[n]{1/n}$ converges to...?

Comment: @professorvector oh, okay

Comment: Since that $|a_{n}|\geq 1 $ and since that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational number so $(a_{n})$ is well-defined, so $R\leq 1$, but how can I prove the other inequality? I want to prove that $R\geq 1$, I can't follow your hints :-(

Comment: Maybe I missed something........$R=\dfrac{1}{\lim\sup|a_n|^{1/n}}$. Since $|a_n|$ never touch any tricky value and is bounded, so the limit supremum below approaches to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. So i get $R=1$, correct me if I'm wrong.. :)

Comment: @Kevin.S Yes, also I think the answer is $R=1$ but how can I prove this formally? Maybe you can write an answer with your solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: It depends how close $\sqrt{3}n\pi$ can be to a multiple of $\pi$. The combination of a transcendental number like $\pi$ and an irrational number like $\sqrt{3}$ might make this entertaining.

Comment: @АлександрПальма The reason I didn't write an answer is because I have to show $\sqrt{3}n\pi$ never gets too closed to an integer. but  I haven't figured out a good way to  bound it.

Comment: @Kevin.S This is a nice and safe problem with a lot of teaching in its solution, a way to learn more math. I've been thinking about it too, but I've been stuck. I hope, some MathSE can enlighten me with a solution.

Comment: @martycohen Transcendental number is not a part of the picture at all. $\sqrt3n\pi$ is close to a multiple of $\pi$ when $\sqrt3n$ is close to an integer.